# Reading pkcs12 certificate information

Tags: java, bouncycastle, jce, pkcs#12

I have a problem with reading certificate information. I want to read full information using java with bouncycastle library in Android programmatically. Now, i'm just using keytool command in console:

```
>keytool -list -keystore 1.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -v
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I've found the solution (below), thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've found solution, the main idea is to cast certificate to x509, then get the SubjectDN and parse values.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        p12.load(new FileInputStream("pkcs.p12"), "password".toCharArray());
        Enumeration<String> e = p12.aliases();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = e.nextElement();
            X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate) p12.getCertificate(alias);
            Principal subject = c.getSubjectDN();
            String subjectArray[] = subject.toString().split(",");
            for (String s : subjectArray) {
                String[] str = s.trim().split("=");
                String key = str[0];
                String value = str[1];
                System.out.println(key + " - " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remember to use java.security.* classes instead of javax.security.*

Comment: Hi @DiegoPlentz  This code doesn't always work. On my machine, p12.getCertificate(alias) returns null. The pfx file was created by openssl as "openssl pkcs12 -export -out 1.pfx -in server.crt -inkey server.key".  I tested your code with another pfx file, which was exported by windows certificate manager, it works fine.

Comment: This is work fine for me but any one know how to install .p12 file on device?

Comment: @ChangmingSun Maybe try passing the "-name" option. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138420/openssl-fails-to-produce-a-pfx-with-a-valid-alias

Comment: @UdayNayak What do you mean "install"? The file can be generated (using openssl), as Changming has done.

Comment: Works fine but with minor fix for NPE:`String value = (str.length > 1) ? str[1] : "";`

Comment: a nice article with bit more details on the same.https://www.pixelstech.net/article/1420427307-Different-types-of-keystore-in-Java----PKCS12