# openssl fails to produce a pfx with a valid alias

Tags: openssl, certificate, keytool, pfx, jarsigner

I am trying to generate a pfx file to use as a signing mechanism for some JAR files as per [these](http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=1681#signing) instructions.

To create the pfx file I am using the following command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my-cert.crt -inkey my-priv-key.key -certfile my-ca-bundle -out my-pfx.pfx
```

This command successfully generates me a pfx file, however, when I try to find the alias using the following command

```
keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my-pfx.pfx -v | grep Alias
```

I get the following response

```
Alias name: 2
```

According to the note linked above (and other research I have done) the Alias returned should look something like this

```
le-d491f28f-ee7b-40e2-b1a7-2b7c3a71979a
```

If I try to use the Alias value I am getting (e.g. 2) using the following command

```
jarsigner -keystore my-pfx.pfx -storetype PKCS12 jacob.jar 2
```

which results in the following error message

```
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: 2.  2 must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.
```

I am totally stumped as to why I am not getting a correct alias.. Any helpful suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try using option `-name "alias"` with command `openssl pkcs12`.

So, the full command may look like (the rest of options were taken from your question):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my-cert.crt -inkey my-priv-key.key -certfile my-ca-bundle -out my-pfx.pfx -name "alias"
```

Comment: Could you explain what `-name` does in this context? According to the docs: `-name friendlyname` _specifies the "friendly name" for the certificate and private key. This name is typically displayed in list boxes by software importing the file._ But how does this change the alias in the p12 file?

Comment: if you still getting failure using this command on windows, recommend to change openssl to this version download here - https://itefix.net/openssl-tool

Comment: @not2savvy After using `-name` argument, run your `keytool -list` command again.  You will see the alias matches.  Is this sufficient?

Comment: @kevinarpe So does `-name` actually set both, the "friendly name" as well as the alias, or are these just two different terms for the same thing?

Comment: @not2savvy Excellent question.  I assume they are the same.